# Веб-сокет не присоединяется к сервер ендпоинт

Tags: maven, java-ee, java, tomcat

Пробую создать веб-приложение с помощью maven на седьмом tomcat-е, но что-то не могу законнектить веб-сокет к серверу, html страницу видно, а соединения нет. Проект успешно собирается и компилируется.

Это структура проекта:

[image: project tree]

Вот мой endpoint:

```
package ru.cadmy.startgame;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value="/startgame")
public class GameEndPoint {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello websockets");  
    }
}
```

Пом

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ru.cadmy</groupId>
  <artifactId>startgame</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>startgame Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.56</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>startgame</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/startgame";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

</script>

<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>

<div id="output"></div>
```

И web.xml, в котором я сильно сомневаюсь:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
        <endpoint name="GameEndPoint" 
        implementation="ru.cadmy.startgame.GameEndPoint"
        url-pattern="/" />
</endpoints>
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как решить?

**UPD: короче, сервер еще нужно конфигурировать в pom-е, а не просто запускать O_o**

Comment: @cadmy, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.